# Spring Boot Scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I have used a Spring Boot Scheduler with @Scheduled annotation along with fixedRateString of 1 sec. This scheduler intermittently stops working for approx 2 min and then starts working automatically. What can be the possible reasons for this behavior and do we have any resolution to this?
Below is the code snippet for the scheduler.
[image]

Comment: add your code so we can understand the cause better

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos 
 Sure ,I have added the snippets.

Answer (score 1):

1st) Please read SO [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type
> the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for
> diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible
> to describe accurately via text.

2nd) To your problem

You use a xml spring based configuration where you have configured your sheduler. Then you also use the annotation `@Scheduled`. You should not mix those 2 different types of configuring beans.

Also you use some type of thread synchronization into this method. Probably some thread is stuck outside of the method because of the lock and this messes the functionality that you want.

Clean either the xml configuration or the annotation for scheduling and try with debug to see why the method behaves as it does which most probable would be from what I have mentioned above about the locks and the multiple configurations.

Comment: I dont use thread synchronization in the method,its just a normal if condition where I check the flag. But yes will definitely try cleaning out xml configuration and then check the behaviour of the scheduler.Thanx for the help!!

Comment: For the above issue ,there is no xml configuration used for scheduling. Only annotations have been used for scheduling.

Comment: Will this configuration :- [ spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=20] resolve the issue?